# Confirm phone call before dialing?

Tags: ios

I saw some reference that iOS 10.4 had introduced a "confirm call" feature.  I can not find any such feature in my *iPhone 6S* with *iOS 14.7.1*.

Is this a third party only feature?

I'm getting killed by accidental calls ("butt calls" as well as misdials due to fat-fingering entries in the contacts list etc) when in either Recents or Contacts. I would prefer the confirmation approach to auto-lock or other more heavy measures.

**Update** six months later (April 2022). This lack of confirmation of calls is a *daily* source of trouble. I have a newer old iPhone 6s that is incredibly sensitive to taps.  Problem is that all the third party apps that provide a "confirmation" seem to be heavy like a battleship: they intend to be an all encompassing communications manager. I just want a "confirm this call" dialog box - nothing more.

Comment: Why not just switch the phone off before you put it in your pocket? That's what everybody else has had to learn to do, since long before we had smart phones.

Comment: I hit the wrong number when in Contacts *when I was actively using the App*. . It happens in various scenarios, please do not over-simplify. . In addition the "cost" of dialing a bad number can be quite high since disturbing folks that want to be left alone causes serious problems.

Comment: This may lead to the same result as mandatory "do you really want to delete FILENAME" confirmations when deleting files: You get so used to the prompt that you confirm it automatically withouth rereading the phone number.

Comment: @nohillside  Yes it could do that but actually I appreciate that confirmation in some other contexts so for me personally it is a functional/useful extra step even in the asymptotic.

Comment: Looking in **Settings** > **Phone** and also in **Accessibility**,  in **iOS** 14.8, I do not see anything that would enable a _confirmation dialog_ when making a call. I'd imagine if it was not in either of those two _settings_ it probably doesn't exist as a built-in feature.

Comment: Googling, I see there is a **ConfirmToSend** for jailbroken phones.

Comment: @user3439894  Thanks for checking : I had not thought to look inside *Accessibility* settings.   Yes I had looked at *ConfirmToSend* but am supremely uninterested in jailbreaking the phone.

Comment: FWIW I was given a promotional pen that has that hollow soft rubber/thermoplastic top that works great on the screens of **iDevices** in place of one's finger. It has greatly cut down on the number of typing mistakes I used to make. I've actually gotten quite fast with it and mistakes are too few to even remember in comparison to just using my fingers.

Comment: I’d also love to have this feature for the same reasons as @WestCoastProjects. I’ve fat fingered the contact list a few times too which is pretty scary if you accidentally call someone you really don’t want to talk to right now. For now it sounds like we’re “holding it wrong” (Apple’s way of blaming problems on the user).